# sms authentication with API REST using templateRoles

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to send a document using a template with the API REST.
I'm using templateRoles in my JSON and i send the name and the mail of the signer who has the rolename defined in the template.

So i have this part of request :

```
"templateId":"894848C-26A8-44B4-B08D-D9140B70EB1A",
"templateRoles":[
    {
        "roleName":"CUSTOMER_SIGNER",
        "name":"Test",
        "email":"test@test.com",
    }
]
```

Now, i want to use sms authentication for my role CUSTOMER_SIGNER.
But in the doc of REST API, there no option for that.

I have try on the model of send a document without template :

```
"templateId":"894848C-26A8-44B4-B08D-D9140B70EB1A",
"templateRoles":[
    {
        "roleName":"CUSTOMER_SIGNER",
        "name":"Test",
        "email":"test@test.com",
        "smsAuthentication":{
            "senderProvidedNumbers":[
                "+00202156511"
            ]
        },
        "requireIdLookup":"true",
        "idCheckConfigurationName":"SMS Auth $",
        "phoneAuthentication":{
            "recipMayProvideNumber":"true"
        }           
    }
]
```

without success. I don't recieve anything.

Have you an idea to make this?

Comment: Hi Boromir, SMS auth is a paid account feature and as such is not enabled by default in dev accounts (even though it's probably just pennies per sms).  Please reach out to your DocuSign Account Manager and they should be able to enable this on your dev account so you can test...

Comment: Hi Ergin, Thanks for your answer. In fact, i have already SMS auth in my account. It works when i use recipient whitout template with API REST, i recieve sms on my phone. It's only when i use template with templateRoles that it doesn't work and i recieve any sms.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? From what i can tell you are actually specifying parameters for both SMS and Phone/Voice authentication here. You will want to remove the phoneAuthentication portion as that is for phone/voice. Here is an example of the smsAuthentication block i'd use:     "requireIdLookup": "false",
                          "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                               "smsAuthentication": {
                              "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                                "+00202156599"
                              ]
                            },

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add sms Authentication to template roles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749933/how-to-add-sms-authentication-to-template-roles)