# How to add sms Authentication to template roles?

Tags: docusignapi

Using the DocuSign Rest API I'm creating an envelope from a template that has one recipient role that has to sign. On the template creation for that recipient role I have enabled Identity Check -> SMS Auth $. It works fine when I try to sent the envelope from DocuSign portal. However when I try to sent it using the API call I get an error saying: RECIPIENT_SMS_AUTH_PHONE_MISSING: SMS authentication phone number cannot be empty.
The request body has included inside template roles:

```
"SmsAuthentication":{
"senderProvidedNumbers":["recipient_number"] },
"IdCheckConfigurationName":"SMS Auth $",
"RequireIdLookup":true
```

Is there any reason why this won't work when making the API call?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For some reason I can only get this to work by using the `compositeTemplates` request property (i.e. I'm unable to get it to work with just a simple Template).  Note that you need to have SMS authentication enabled in the account you are testing with, if you're testing with a developer sandbox account it should be enabled, if you're in production you can reach out to your account manager.

To get this to work I used the following JSON that uses a composite template:

```
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject": "Please sign this for me",
    "compositeTemplates": [{
        "serverTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "templateId": "[TEMPLATE_ID]"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [{
            "sequence": "1",
            "recipients": {
                "signers": [{
                    "name": "[SIGNER_NAME]",                
                    "email": "[SIGNER_EMAIL]",              
                    "routingOrder": "1",
                    "requireIdLookup": true,
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "idCheckConfigurationName": "SMS Auth $",
                    "smsAuthentication": {
                        "senderProvidedNumbers": [
                            "1234567890"
                        ]
                    }
                }]
            }
        }]
    }]
}
```

I only tested with a U.S. number so not sure about the international number formats, but the above format I've included works for U.S. numbers starting with the area code.

---

**Update**

To get this to work with international numbers add the `roleName` property to the signers object and also add your country code (ie "+55" in this case for Brazil)

Comment: Complementing the answer: I could make it work in Brazil too, but I had to add "roleName" in the signers object and also the country code (+55, in my case) to the mobile number.

Comment: Thanks for sharing with the community jfneis!  I've updated my answer for international #s.

Answer (score 0):

for country code, please set as form below, +84 is VN, leave one space between phone number and country code, it take me a lot of time :(

"senderProvidedNumbers": ["+84 945672509"]

Comment: Please do make use of the text formatting tools available.