# Docusign SMS authentification working but only with the area code +1

Tags: docusignapi

I am working on the docusign API and i want to use the SMS authentification.
But, i can't change the area code witch is by default on +1 (the american AreaCode)

And i can't find on the docusign documentation any help to change this area code to send SMS authentification to other country.

I tried to add "roleName" in the signers object and also the country code (+33, in my case) to the mobile number as as solution from this topic: [How to add sms Authentication to template roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749933/how-to-add-sms-authentication-to-template-roles/34754976#34754976)

But it hasn't work (maybe because i'm not using a template).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I have found the solution during the night! I will share you that:

Comment: Thanks, this is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add "RoleName" in the signers object and also the country code (but use "0033" instead of +33) to the mobile number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJpvJ.png)

Then on you form, don't overwrite on the +33 you have to keep it and write after it your phone number.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU6Zc.png)  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5XbG.png)

Finally you will see the phone number you enter as a choice to send the SMS to the signer.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K56xs.png)

Anyway thank you Inbar Gazit for your fast response, i hope what i find will help others.

Answer (score 1):

for country code please set as form below +84 is VN, leave one space between phone, it take me a lot of time :(

"senderProvidedNumbers": ["+84 945672509"]