# Adding SMS auth to templateRoles embedded signing

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to add SMS auth to an embedded envelope that uses template roles, but I'm not having any luck. The envelope and envelope views are created without errors, but the signers are never asked to authenticate via SMS before they view or sign. They currently sign and complete without any additional prompts to first authenticate.

What I've tried so far:

- I am still in the admin demo developing my proof of concept, but I did verify that **Phone Authentication** is enabled with **SMS or Phone Call** in **Settings > Identity Verification**. I also verbally confirmed this is active with my Sales/Support contacts.
- I copied my `workflowId` from the `accounts/{account_id}/identity_verification` endpoint. (It says it is for **Phone Authentication**.)
- I found the SO question [How to add sms Authentication to template roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749933/how-to-add-sms-authentication-to-template-roles) but it suggests the only solution is to use `compositeTemplates`. Are `compositeTemplates` *required* for SMS auth, or can I add SMS auth using the basic template reference model I'm using below?
- Here is my current envelope definition:

```
{
  "brandId": "{{docusign.brand_id}}",
  "templateId": "{{docusign.template_id}}",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "roleName": "Qualifier",
      "email": "john.doe@email.com",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "clientUserId": "123456789",
      "templateAccessCodeRequired": null,
      "identityVerification": {
        "workflowId": "{{docusign.workflow_id}}",
        "steps": null,
        "inputOptions": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number_list",
            "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
            "phoneNumberList": [
              {
                "countryCode": "1",
                "number": "5555551234"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "city",
            "value": "My City"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "state",
            "value": "My State"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "company",
            "value": "Acme Corp"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "roleName": "Guest",
      "email": "jane.doe@email.com",
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "clientUserId": "234567891",
      "templateAccessCodeRequired": null,
      "identityVerification": {
        "workflowId": "{{docusign.workflow_id}}",
        "steps": null,
        "inputOptions": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number_list",
            "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
            "phoneNumberList": [
              {
                "countryCode": "1",
                "number": "5555552345"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "city",
            "value": "My City"
          },
          {
            "tabLabel": "state",
            "value": "Michigan"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "registration_id",
        "required": "true",
        "show": "true",
        "value": "123456"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

---

---

### My Full Solution...

I accept @Inbar's answer as correct, as it was what got me to this point. But a couple other things held me up, so I'll outline all my API calls in case it helps someone or if there is other feedback.

#### 1. Create envelope from template:

Note: `"status"` must be left as `"created"` at this point.

**POST:** `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes`

```
{
  "brandId": "{{brand_id}}",
  "templateId": "{{template_id}}",
  "status": "created",
  /* comment: below this is a custom field only specific to my app */
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      {
        "name": "registration_id",
        "required": "true",
        "show": "true",
        "value": "{{registration_id}}"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

#### 2. Update envelope recipients, add identityVerification to each:

If I tried to GET my envelope above at this stage, it already has two empty recipients in `recipientId` 1 and 2 (because my template has two recipients), so in the following call I had to PUT them and reference those recipientIds to overwrite the blank recipients with my correct recipient details. (I initially POSTed them, but ended up with four recipients instead of two.)

Note: you'll have to get your `{{ workflow_id }}` referenced below ahead of time by [calling GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/identity_verification](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/accounts/identityverifications/list/).

**PUT:** `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/{{envelope_id}}/recipients`

```
{
  "signers": [
    {
      "name": "John Doe",
      "email": "john.doe@email.com",
      "roleName": "Qualifier",
      "note": "",
      "notaryNote": "",
      "routingOrder": 1,
      "status": "created",
      "templateAccessCodeRequired": null,
      "deliveryMethod": "email",
      "consentDetailsList": null,
      "accessCodeRequired": false,
      "creationReason": "sender",
      "isBulkRecipient": false,
      "requiredUploadSignature": false,
      "firstName": "John",
      "lastName": "Doe",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "clientUserId": "12345",
      "requireIdLookup": false,
      "identityVerification": {
        "workflowId": "{{ workflow_id }}",
        "steps": null,
        "inputOptions": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number_list",
            "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
            "phoneNumberList": [
              {
                "countryCode": "1",
                "code": "1",
                "countryCodeLock": false,
                "number": "5555555555"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]           

      },
      "completedCount": "0",
      "recipientType": "signer",
      "idCheckConfigurationName": ""
    },
    {
      "name": "Jane Doe",
      "email": "jane.doe@email.com",
      "roleName": "Guest",
      "recipientId": "2",
      ...etc...
    }
  ]
}
```

#### 3. Update Envelope Status to Sent:

This step is required, otherwise step 4 will error with `ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS: Invalid envelope status. Envelope not yet sent.`

**PUT:** `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/{{envelope_id}}`

```
{
  "status": "sent"
}
```

#### 4. Create Recipient View(s):

**POST:** `/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/{{envelope_id}}/views/recipient`

```
{
  "returnUrl": "{{ your_website_return_url }}",
  "authenticationMethod": "none",
  "email": "john.doe@email.com",
  "userName": "John Doe",
  "clientUserId": "12345"
}
```

...and again for Jane Doe.

Grabbing the URL in these responses gave me a URL that prompted me for phone authentication before I was able to sign.

Comment: Do you want this template to *always* use SMS Auth, or you want your code to decide that?

Comment: It should always use SMS auth (but don't mind if code decides), but the number via which they authenticate will change depending on the recipient's phone number. I added more questions below your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There are two ways to do this:

 1. You change your original template, manually, to include SMS auth as part of the authentication. This is good enough if the phone number to authenticate is fixed.


 2. If you want to dynamically do this, you have to make several API calls. You first create the envelope in "draft" status. You don't send it, so your line "  `"status": "sent"` should be changed to `"status": "created". After this you make another API call to update recipients:

PUT /restapi/v2.1/accounts/[[AccountId]/envelopes/[[EnvelopeId]]/recipients

{
  "signers": [
    {
      "name": "Inbar Gazit",
      "email": "inbar.gazit@docusign.com",
      "roleName": "test",
      "note": "",
      "notaryNote": "",
      "routingOrder": 1,
      "status": "created",
      "templateAccessCodeRequired": null,
      "deliveryMethod": "email",
      "consentDetailsList": null,
      "accessCodeRequired": "false",
      "creationReason": "sender",
      "isBulkRecipient": false,
      "requireUploadSignature": false,
      "firstName": "",
      "lastName": "",
      "recipientId": "1",
      "requireIdLookup": false,
      "identityVerification": {
        "workflowId": "c368e411-1592-4001-a3df-dca94ac539ae",
        "steps": null,
        "inputOptions": [
          {
            "name": "phone_number_list",
            "valueType": "PhoneNumberList",
            "phoneNumberList": [
              {
                "countryCode": "1",
                "code": "1",
                "countryCodeLock": false,
                "number": "[[PHONE_NUMBER]]"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "completedCount": "0",
      "recipientType": "signer",
      "idCheckConfigurationName": ""
    }
  ],
  "carbonCopies": []
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Couple questions. 1 - If I create envelope with "status": "draft", I receive error: INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER, "Invalid value for 'status' in envelope definition. Only 'sent' or 'created' (default) are allowed." If I change to "status": "created" then it lets me create the envelope and add recipients. Is "created" ok? 2 - After I've added recipients, I try to create recipient views with /accounts/{{account_id}}/envelopes/{{envelope_id}}/views/recipient, but I get ENVELOPE_INVALID_STATUS, "Envelope not yet sent." Do I need another API call to update status again?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, "created" not "draft", fixing my answer

Comment: Thank you. I added my entire process above, below my original question.